# EXCEL: Fill Series Not Working

Tags: excel

Simple question.

Why is my autofill series (double clicking the square on the bottom right) not working when I use this code:

```
=if(and(isnumber(search("word", B2)), isnumber(search("other word", B2))), substitute(B2, B2, "new word"), B2)
```

But works when I use the code:

```
=if(isnumber(search("word", B2)), substitute(B2, B2, "New Word"), B2)
```

Both are data type "general".

Has anyone had the problem where sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't, and has figured it out? There are no blank spaces in my worksheet BTW.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Do you mean as in it returns an error, or as in it doesn't return your expected result?

Comment: Also, your use of `SUBSTITUTE` is entirely superfluous. `=SUBSTITUTE(B2,B2,"New Word")` is the same thing as just `="New Word"`

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 Working means double-clicking the square and having it autofill every cell below possible. Not working means I double-click, and nothing happens. I can only auto-fill by manually dragging the highlighted box.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with this auto-fill feature because I've never used it. Why is it an issue to manually click and drag the formula in highlighted box?

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 It would be great if it wasn't an issue, but I have 220,000 rows of data, and it would take about 4 minutes to drag through it all for every change I want to make :(

Comment: Ah, I see your point. Sorry I can't help. There is nothing syntactically invalid in your first formula, so I'm not sure why it wouldn't work.

Comment: @AndrewWolfe- put formula in C2, select b2, tap ctrl+<down arrow>, go to column C on the last row, tap shift+ctrl+<up arrow>, tap Ctrl+D.

Comment: Given your sample, `isnumber(search("word", B2))` is completely redundant. Can you supply something closer to a real-world sample together with expected results?

Comment: @Jeeped Actually, your response above was right on. If you re-post it as an answer, I'll mark it as the correct answer. :)

Comment: @AndrewWolfe - No offense but that is sort of a SuperUser.com question, not StackOverflow.com. Maybe we just chalk this up to a typographical error and let it be.

Comment: @Jeeped if that's what you think is best, I have no preference. But thanks for the answer

Comment: BTW double-clicking the fill handle only works if there is something in the column next to it, both the original formulas work if this is the case.